# Record video in iOS app without leaving app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, cordova, phonegap-plugins

PhoneGap offers a plug-in for recording video, but [this plug-in](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media-capture.git) seems to force users to leave the app for the Camera app in order to record video.

Is it possible to initiate and stop video recording without leaving the app?

The two methods below are the primary methods we are using (rest of plug-in is viewable from the link above) to capture video. How should we modify this to allow recording from the front camera, without leaving the app, when the user taps a button?

Can anyone provide guidance please? Thanks.

**Capture.m:**

```
- (void)captureVideo:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    NSString* callbackId = command.callbackId;
    NSDictionary* options = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([options isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    }

    // options could contain limit, duration and mode
    // taking more than one video (limit) is only supported if provide own controls via cameraOverlayView property
    NSNumber* duration = [options objectForKey:@"duration"];
    NSString* mediaType = nil;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        // there is a camera, it is available, make sure it can do movies
        pickerController = [[CDVImagePicker alloc] init];

        NSArray* types = nil;
        if ([UIImagePickerController respondsToSelector:@selector(availableMediaTypesForSourceType:)]) {
            types = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
            // NSLog(@"MediaTypes: %@", [types description]);

            if ([types containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie]) {
                mediaType = (NSString*)kUTTypeMovie;
            } else if ([types containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeVideo]) {
                mediaType = (NSString*)kUTTypeVideo;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!mediaType) {
        // don't have video camera return error
        NSLog(@"Capture.captureVideo: video mode not available.");
        CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageToErrorObject:CAPTURE_NOT_SUPPORTED];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:callbackId];
        pickerController = nil;
    } else {
        pickerController.delegate = self;
        pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        pickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
        // iOS 3.0
        pickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mediaType, nil];

        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie]){
            if (duration) {
                pickerController.videoMaximumDuration = [duration doubleValue];
            }
            //NSLog(@"pickerController.videoMaximumDuration = %f", pickerController.videoMaximumDuration);
        }

        // iOS 4.0
        if ([pickerController respondsToSelector:@selector(cameraCaptureMode)]) {
            pickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
            // pickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
            // pickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
            // pickerController.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
        }
        // CDVImagePicker specific property
        pickerController.callbackId = callbackId;

        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"presentViewController:animated:completion:");
        if ([self.viewController respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            [self.viewController presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else {
            // deprecated as of iOS >= 6.0
            [self.viewController presentModalViewController:pickerController animated:YES];
        }
    }
}

- (CDVPluginResult*)processVideo:(NSString*)moviePath forCallbackId:(NSString*)callbackId
{
    // save the movie to photo album (only avail as of iOS 3.1)

    /* don't need, it should automatically get saved
     NSLog(@"can save %@: %d ?", moviePath, UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath));
    if (&UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum != NULL && UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath) == YES) {
        NSLog(@"try to save movie");
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
        NSLog(@"finished saving movie");
    }*/
    // create MediaFile object
    NSDictionary* fileDict = [self getMediaDictionaryFromPath:moviePath ofType:nil];
    NSArray* fileArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:fileDict];

    return [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsArray:fileArray];
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with PhoneGap, but according to your `Objective-C`  code you are not leaving the app. Code just presents modal view controller and this is the simplest way to record a video.